# How to keep a user logged in after a long time offline in PWA?

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I want to make my application as a PWA,
but I faced such a problem, after login, the user token works for 8 hours. What to do if a person has been using the application for more than 8 hours and has cached a certain amount of data and requests.
 After he turns on the Internet, he will be logged out and all this will not make sense.
What is the right thing to do in such cases?